# Weird behaviour with triggering __callStatic() from non-static method

Tags: php

I found this weird behaviour with PHP classes (v5.3.8).

You have:

```
class foo {
  function __call($func, $args) {
    if ($func == 'bar')
      echo "non-static __call";
  }

  static function __callStatic($func, $args) {
    if ($func == 'bar')
      echo "__callStatic";
  }

  function callMe() {
    self::bar();
  }
}
```

Then you do:

```
foo::bar() // outputs '__callStatic' as expected.
$f = new foo;
$f->callMe(); // outputs 'non-static __call', as I did not expect.
```

You see, a non-existent static method called from a non-static function triggers `__call()` instead of `__callStatic()`. I was wondering if this is supposed to work like this or is this some kind of bug?

**[EDIT]**

I forgot to try `static::bar();` on `callMe()` but no, it didn't work either.

I (think I) understand inhan's comment but still... if I'm calling the class itself, not the instance or object, immediate logic for me says it should trigger __callStatic(). Oh well.

Thank you for your answers/comments.

Comment: PHP has a huge pile of these weird behaviours... :/ The manual says "__callStatic is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static *context*", which suggests that this might be the expected behaviour. but it certainly doesn't make much sense. it's totally counterintuitive

Comment: `callMe` is a **non-static function** (in the object scope) so even though you're calling a non-existent method, you're still dealing with the object instance itself, so naturally `__call` is executed.

Comment: It is weird, though. If you change `self::bar();` to `foo::bar()`, it will still be invoked non-statically, even though that is clearly a static call.

Comment: @webbiedave, `foo::bar()` is not clearly a static call. It is perfectly valid to call a non-static method like that from within a class to specify exactly which method to call in the case of inheritance.

Comment: @Matthew: Of course you're correct. My cat got at the keyboard again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be confused by what these things mean from within the context of a class method:

```
class B extends A {
  public function test() {
    A::foo();
    self::foo();
    static::foo();
  }
}
```

*None* of those mean "call the static method named foo." It simply means "call the method named foo" at the place in the inheritance tree as specified by what is left of the colons.

Normally, without magic, you only have one function named `foo`, so the meaning is straightforward. However, when you overload with *both* magic methods, the call is *ambiguous*. PHP defaults to using `__call()` before `__callStatic()`.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods, variables belongs to classes not to objects so i think this is supposed to work like this.

Comment: huh? could you explain a bit further? I don't see the connection

Comment: Some explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Class_methods

Comment: you don't need to explain that to *me*. So, again, why do you think it supposed to work like this?

Comment: My bad. inhand had explained the main concept of this behavior.