# The mysterious behaviour of __callStatic method

Tags: php

SO question [Weird behaviour with triggering __callStatic() from non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469317/weird-behaviour-with-triggering-callstatic-from-non-static-method) is great because it explains the weird behaviour with the __callStatic not being called from within the class itself (Note that I don't see this behaviour in 5.3.3 but in 5.3.8 and 5.3.12). It seems that the __callStatic can only be invoked from outside the class. That's now a fact. But what do I do if I really want the __callStatic to be called from within my class? What syntax should I use to get over the issue?

Comment: Can you include a test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not have to be from outside the class, just not from object context (i.e. where `$this` is an instance of the class). So you can wrap this call in a static method, for example:

```
class TestCallStatic
{
    public function __call($func, $args)
    {
        echo "__call($func)";
    }

    public static function __callStatic($func, $args)
    {
        echo "__callStatic($func)";
    }

    public function test()
    {
        self::_test();
    }
    protected static function _test()
    {
        self::i_am_static();
    }
}

$test = new TestCallStatic();
$test->test();
```

Output:

> __callStatic(i_am_static)

Comment: That was the solution. It is to make understand the php interpreter that you want to call a static function. By using the helper static function _test you avoid the ambiguous call. The only difference in my code is the need to use $this so: self::_test($this); and static function _test($myClassInstance)

Comment: I would try to separate the part that needs `$this` from the part that does not (only move "static" part into `_test`) - if that is possible with your class. It makes encapsulation easier and the code will look cleaner.

Comment: Tested successfully on 5.3.3, 5.3.8 and 5.3.12

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract the functionality to another method like Class::magicCall($method, $args) and call that from within __callStatic(). That way you can also access that functionality by simply calling Class::magicCall() directly.